# Referencing beamer slides numbers not all slides are shown (undefined reference error)

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing

I have a slide that's incrementally opened. Say it has normally n slides. But "now" I decide to to not start at slide 1, say at slide 2. Although there still n-1 slides shown, LaTeX still decides that it can't find the label-definition anymore! How do I resolve this problem?

I provide a minimal example below. Note that I duplicated all slides so that I can define the label both as an argument to the slide as well as in the 'usual way' -- just to show that this doesn't change anything.

Here the code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}<2->{Title of Slide 1}\label{LabelOfSlideOne}
  Slide 1 has three subslides, opened one by one, normally. Here, however, we start at slide number 2!
  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item 1
    \item 2
    \item 3
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}<2->[label=LabelOfSlideTwo]{Title of Slide 2}
  Slide 2 is exactly as slide 1, we simply define the label differently.
  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item 1
    \item 2
    \item 3
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{Title of Slide 3}\label{LabelOfSlideThree}
  Slide 3 has two subslides, we show them incrementally, as normal.
  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item 1
    \item 2
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}[label=LabelOfSlideFour]{Title of Slide 4}
  Slide 4 is exactly as slide 3, we simply define the label differently.
  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item 1
    \item 2
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{Slide 5: Test all the references!}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item This should show a 1: \ref{LabelOfSlideOne}
    \item This should show a 2: \ref{LabelOfSlideTwo}
    \item This should show a 3: \ref{LabelOfSlideThree}
    \item This should show a 4: \ref{LabelOfSlideFour}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

That's the result:

[image]

This shows that whereas *normally* defining labels works perfectly (the last two slides), it does not work when we do not show all slides (the first two slides).

**So... How to solve this issue?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways in which you can avoid the problem:

- you could specify the label on a particular overlay, e.g. `\label<2>{LabelOfSlideOne}`
- you could reference a particular overlay of a label, e.g. `\ref{LabelOfSlideTwo<2>}`

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}<2->{Title of Slide 1}\label<2>{LabelOfSlideOne}
  Slide 1 has three subslides, opened one by one, normally. Here, however, we start at slide number 2!
  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item 1
    \item 2
    \item 3
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}<2->[label=LabelOfSlideTwo]{Title of Slide 2}
  Slide 2 is exactly as slide 1, we simply define the label differently.
  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item 1
    \item 2
    \item 3
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{Title of Slide 3}\label{LabelOfSlideThree}
  Slide 3 has two subslides, we show them incrementally, as normal.
  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item 1
    \item 2
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}[label=LabelOfSlideFour]{Title of Slide 4}
  Slide 4 is exactly as slide 3, we simply define the label differently.
  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item 1
    \item 2
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{Slide 5: Test all the references!}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item This should show a 1: \ref{LabelOfSlideOne}
    \item This should show a 2: \ref{LabelOfSlideTwo<2>}
    \item This should show a 3: \ref{LabelOfSlideThree}
    \item This should show a 4: \ref{LabelOfSlideFour}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks tons! I didn't even know that's correct syntax! :)

Comment: @Prof.Chaos You're welcome!